# Changing XML with Linq

Tags: xml, linq, xpath

I have an XML written which is the following:

```
<ArrayOfProductLine>
    <ProductLine>
        <Name>CRM</Name>
        <ActionFields>
            <ActionField Id="1">
                <Name>A2</Name>
            </ActionField>
            <ActionField Id="2">
                <Name>A1</Name>
            </ActionField>
        </ActionFields>
        <ProcessSteps>
            <ProcessStep>
                <Name>Marketing</Name>
                <LearningObjectives>
                    <LearningObjective ActionFieldId="1">
                        <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph AllowSelection="false">
                                <Text>Lern Ziel2</Text>
                                <Id>1</Id>
                            </Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph AllowSelection="false">
                                <Text>test</Text>
                                <Id>4</Id>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </Paragraphs>
                    </LearningObjective>
                    <LearningObjective ActionFieldId="2">
                        <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph AllowSelection="false">
                                <Text>Lern Ziel2.1</Text>
                                <Id>2</Id>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </Paragraphs>
                    </LearningObjective>
                </LearningObjectives>
            </ProcessStep>
            <ProcessStep>
                <Name>Vertrieb</Name>
                <LearningObjectives>
                    <LearningObjective ActionFieldId="1">
                        <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph AllowSelection="false">
                                <Id>3</Id>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </Paragraphs>
                    </LearningObjective>
                </LearningObjectives>
            </ProcessStep>
        </ProcessSteps>
    </ProductLine>
</ArrayOfProductLine>
```

I want to read this XML and count maximum of the LearningObjective nodes and write back empty LearningObjective nodes in the LearningObjectives node if the number of LearningObjective nodes are less than the Maximum number of Learning objective nodes using Linq to XML. I am quite new to Linq. Can any one please help me about changing this XML.

Comment: What do you have so far (besides these requirements)? And what `maximum` of LearningObjective nodes mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we should split this up a bit:

- Loading the XML
- Finding all the `LearningObjectives` container elements
- Counting the `LearningObjective` elements within each container
- Finding the maximum value of those counts
- Adding empty elements where necessary

The first four are actually pretty straightforward:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var containers = doc.Descendants("LearningObjectives").ToList();
var containerCounts = containers.Select(x => x.Elements("LearningObjectives")
                                              .Count());
var maxCount = containerCounts.Max();
```

I would quite possibly have combined the last two statements, but I wanted to separate them out for clarity in the answer.

For the final part, I would suggest *not* actually using LINQ - it's not a good fit for mutations. All we need to do is look at all the containers, and add the right number of elements to each one:

```
foreach (var container in containers)
{
    // Same approach to counting as before.
    int count = x => x.Elements("LearningObjectives").Count()
    for (int i = count; i < maxCount; i++)
    {
        container.Add(new XElement("LearningObjective"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. I tried with your steps. Its giving the almost same result which I mentioned. If I want to set the Attribute ActionFieldId to the empty LearningObjective, I need to  get all ActionFieldIds and find it the current LearningObjectives missing any Id then create LearningObjective node with that missing ActionFieldId?

Comment: @user2331747: I don't really see what you mean, to be honest... you didn't mention anything about setting the attribute in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was no need of setting attribute to LearningObjective. But in the front end, we do need to have that attribute for empty LearningObjective nodes as well. What I mean to say is having the empty node like this:<LearningObjective ActionFieldId="1">

Comment: @user2331747: Okay - so perhaps you just need `new XAttribute("ActionFieldId", i + 1)` as a second argument to the `XElement` constructor.